# Linq: Order by parentID

Tags: vb.net, linq

Having this class...

```
Public Class Employee
    Public Property ID As Guid
    Public Property ParentID As Nullable(Of Guid)
End Class
```

It's not a tree, but a list - therefor ParentID is unique and can occur only once.

How do I in Linq (using vb.net) sort it by "ParentID" (empty ParentID first)?

Comment: How do you propose to "order" a guid?  There are lots of different ways it can be done.

Comment: Sry for not being clear - I updated my question. Well there's only one Employee with empty parentID and ParentIDs are unique, so there's only one sort order - question is if it can be sorted using Linq?

Answer (score 0):

The null `Guid`s sort first by default, so you can just use [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
employees = employees.OrderBy(Function(e) e.ParentID).ToList()
```

Or if you prefer query syntax:

```
employees = (From e In employees Order By e.ParentID).ToList()
```